# Is there a way to write style that will always come after mixins are included?

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I am facing a problem with the SCSS mixins whereby I have to repeat the same code to get the work done. I have the following SCSS code:

```
@mixin column($count, $size) { // Can not make any change in this code.
  width: getWidth($count, $size);
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

@mixin desktop {
  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@mixin tablet {
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    @content;
  }
}

@function getWidth($count, $size) {
  @return 50; // For example purpose only.
}

.c {
  @include desktop {
    @include column(10, large);
  }

  @include desktop {
    @include column(11, large);
  }

  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

which is compiled into:

```
.c {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .c {
    width: 50;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .c {
    width: 50;
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
  }
}
```

The problem here is that **margin** is overwritten by the mixins. Or I have to repeat the same code(duplicate code) like below:

```
.c {
  @include desktop {
    @include column(10, large);
    margin: 0 auto; // Duplicate
  }

  @include desktop {
    @include column(11, large);
    margin: 0 auto; // Duplicate
  }

  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to get:

```
.c {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .c {
      width: 50;
      margin-left: 3%;
      margin-right: 3%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .c {
      width: 50;
      margin-left: 3%;
      margin-right: 3%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
```

Is there any better way to remove this duplicate code so that I have to write code only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to see if the `@media` query comes after makes you happy.

```
.c {
  @include desktop {
    @include column(10, large);
  }
  @include desktop {
    @include column(11, large);
  }
  & {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Modified a little bit. So, no need to repeat classname.

`.c {
  @include desktop {
    @include column(10, large);
  }

  @include desktop {
    @include column(11, large);
  }

  & {
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
}`

Comment: Cool syntax, I updated the answer accordingly, please consider giving it an upvote if it somehow helped you find the answer easier.